# Call addScriptMessageHandler after adding WKWebView to view

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, wkwebview

I have added `WKWebView` to view via code in my class which extends `UIViewController` class, I am able to call `JS` function from iOS storyboard buttons successfully.

However, I want `JS` to be able to tell `Swift` when an `ajax` `post` request is complete... Luckily I found this page...
http://www.kinderas.com/technology/2014/6/15/wkwebview-and-javascript-in-ios-8-using-swift

```
var contentController = WKUserContentController()
contentController.addScriptMessageHandler(
    self,
    name: "callbackHandler"
)

var config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
config.userContentController = contentController

self.webView = WKWebView(
    frame: self.containerView.bounds,
    configuration: config
)
```

Here... I want to be able add script message handler after the `webview` is added to `view`.

Is it possible to call `addScriptMessageHandler()` after webview is already added to the view?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, and it's really simple too:

```
let contentController = self.webView.configuration.userContentController
contentController.addScriptMessageHandler(self, name: "callbackHandler2")
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question ;P

Though @CodeDifferent's answer works a treat :D

But we can make it even simpler by doing this...

```
self.webView.configuration.userContentController.addScriptMessageHandler(
    self,
    name: "callbackHandler"
)
```

or more compact...

```
self.webView.configuration.userContentController.addScriptMessageHandler(self,name: "callbackHandler")
```

This is what I used, works like a charm :)